# Can't call a method from within a class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I attempt to run my code I get the error message 'No overload for method 'talk' takes 0 arguments', could someone help me call the talk() method please. Sorry for the long amount of code but I honestly don't understand were I'm going wrong.

```
class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Critter newcritter = new Critter();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter critter name: ");

        var newname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        newcritter.Name = newname;

        Console.WriteLine("Say Hello to your new critter, {0}!", newcritter.Name);

        var option = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        while (option != "0")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"
            Critter Caretaker

             0 - Quit
              1 - Listen to your critter
              2 - Feed your critter
              3 - Play with your critter
              ");
            if (option == "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good-bye.");
            }

            if (option == "1")
            {
                newcritter.talk();
            }

class Critter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hunger = 0;
        public int Boredom = 0;

        public void PassTime()
        {
            Hunger += 1;
            Boredom += 1;
        }

        public void mood()
        {
            var unhappiness = Hunger + Boredom;
            string m = "";
            if (unhappiness < 5)
            {
                m = "Happy";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 5 && 
                unhappiness <= 10)
            {
                m = "Okay";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 11 &&
                unhappiness <= 15)
            {
                m = "Frustrated";
            }

            if (unhappiness <= 16)
            {
                m = "Mad";
            }
        }

        public void talk(string m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm", Name, "and I feel", m, "now.\n");
            PassTime();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `newcritter.talk();` (without arguments), whereas your method requires one argument `public void talk(string m)`.

So you need to pass an argument (`string`) to the `talk` method:

```
newcritter.talk("GOOD");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `talk` method expects a string parameter, so you need to provide one:

```
newcritter.talk("fine");
```

Also, the way you're calling [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here is wrong. Try this instead:

```
public void talk(string m)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm {0} and I feel {1} now.", Name, m);
    PassTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a line of code calling talk:

```
 if (option == "1")
 {
     newcritter.talk();
 }
```

Here's your defintion of talk:

```
public void talk(string m)
```

I think the error is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`Error` `Describes` it more clearly:

there is no method `talk` with 0 arguments:

i think this :

```
if (option == "1")
            {
                newcritter.talk();//error here as there no zero argument talk() method
            }
```

Should be:

```
if (option == "1")
            {
               newcritter.talk("somestring");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some thing in this code. You haven't specify the what you need to do.
As i understood your while in **Program**  class should be.

```
    while (option != "0")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"
        Critter Caretaker

         0 - Quit
          1 - Listen to your critter
          2 - Feed your critter
          3 - Play with your critter
          ");
        if (option == "0")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good-bye.");
        }

        if (option == "1")
        {
            newcritter.talk();
        }
         if (option == "2")
        {
            newcritter.PassTime();
        }
        if (option == "3")
        {
            newcritter.mood();
        }
    }
```

And your Crtter class should be

```
class Critter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Hunger = 0;
    public int Boredom = 0;
    public string m = "Happy";

   // No Change in PassTime() method and  mood() method
   //
    public void talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm", Name, "and I feel", m, "now.\n");
        PassTime();
    }
```